# Processing Azure SSAS Cube from On-Premises SSIS: Do I need a dummy Office365 Account?

Tags: azure, ssis, ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

We have a cube in Azure, but SQL Server on-prem running the nightly processing jobs. Since SSIS connects to Azure with Office 365 username and login, do we need to create a dummy office 365 account to run services?

Answer (score 1):

No - you can register a new Web App on Azure, give that app admin permission on Azure Analysis Services, and then use the app ID and Key when connecting to Azure AS from SSIS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-integrate-apps-with-azure-ad#to-register-a-new-application-using-the-azure-portal